Only show taxonomy on top level posts
Is there a simple way of only showing a custom taxonomy on top level posts for a custom post type in admin interface?
Example: I have a CPT, product, and a custom taxonomy called color. But I only want the color options to be visible on parent (top level) posts in admin.
